# launch spark job from bash taking parameters from a text file

Tags: bash, apache-spark

I am running a standalone spark instance that I launch with:

```
/usr/local/spark-1.6.0/bin/spark-submit --class "run.Main" --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --driver-memory 45G --jars $(echo /var/myapp/lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') mycoolapp.jar "local[6]" "parA" "parB" "parC" "parD"
```

what I do manually is to launch it for a specific "parA" value.

Then, once is finished, I relaunch it with a new value for "parA". I have all the possible "parA" values listed in a .txt files, and I am wondering if it's possible to write a bash script that does this for me, i.e. launching the script and automatically picking the next "parA" value from the text file.

Of course, I need that it waits to have finished a Spark job before launching the next, since I am using Spark on a single machine and each single job eats almost all the RAM on the machine...

any guidance on that is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. You just iterate over an array of arguments. And you no need to worry about how to wait until the end of the job, because submit operation is synchronous.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a parAs=('parA0' 'parA1' 'parA2')

for parA in "${parAs[@]}"; do
    echoString=$(eval echo /var/myapp/lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')
    ./bin/submit ....--jars $echoString...... $parA .....
done
```

Comment: it should be something like that, but I have an error: 
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
I guess I have to escape the 'echo' I have in the launch script? or should I embed it within quotes or something to make it safe?

Comment: no. you should not embed it within quotes. just check syntax. be careful with array declaration: '..parAs=(' there should not be spaces around  equal sign

Comment: actually, I have no spaces, if I remove my spark code, and just echo parA, the array with my values works just fine... so I was thinking that there is an issue that I need to take into account when calling $(echo ....) within a bash script?